# Double integration in polar coordinates between two circles

Tags: integration, circles, polar-coordinates, area

I am trying to integrate converting to polar coordinates, between two circles.

$$A = \iint_D x \,\mathrm{d}A $$

Ant the domain of integration is set to be the region in the first quadrant between the circles:
$x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$

I have plotted the circles, and I suppose the region I am being asked for is what I have painted in red:

[image]

Now, I would know how to proceed if one circle was perfectly inside of the other (same center), I would set $\theta$ to be between $0$ and $\pi / 4$ and $r$ to be between the radius of the smallest circle and the radius of the other one. However, I cannot do any of those here.

So how should I convert this integral to a polar-coordinate integral?
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the image to the post.

Comment: Can you parameterize the inner and outer circles by polar functions $r(\theta)$?

Comment: Thanks Travis. How should I parametrize the inner and outer circles? I was given the formulas I wrote, but I am free to proceed however I like while I get the correct result

Comment: For the second circle, try completing the square.

Comment: Yes @user170231 , I can get it to (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1, but I do not know how to proceed on to get the polar coordinate form from there.

Comment: @vagaerg You're welcome. I just saw your message but see Marconius has given an excellent answer explaining how to do this. In general, replace $x$ with $r \cos \theta$ and $y$ with $r \sin \theta$, simplify, and (attempt to) solve for $r$ as a function of $\theta$.

Comment: @Travis Thanks! My issue was mainly with getting the limits, once I have the domain I know how to integrate in polar coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For circle one, the equation is simply

$$C_1: r=2$$

For circle two $x^2+y^2=r^2,\quad x=r\cos\theta$, so

$$C_2: r^2=2r\cos\theta \implies r(r-2\cos\theta)=0 \implies r=0,r=2\cos\theta$$

Of these only the second solution is useful (the first just says $C_2$ passes through the origin), so the inner and outer radii for the integral are $2\cos\theta$ and $2$, respectively. And $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi/2$ in the first quadrant.

Since $dA=r\,dr\,d\theta$, we get

$$A=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\int_{2\cos\theta}^{2}{r}\,dr\,d\theta}$$

(The original integral for area should have been $A=\iint{dA}$.)

---

If $I=\iint{x\,dA}$ is required, then from $x=r\cos\theta$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\int_{2\cos\theta}^{2}{r^2\cos\theta}\,dr\,d\theta}$$

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you very much!.
Yes, I will change the original integral, I wrote D because that is what we were given (to specify that we needed to change the domain)